# How to save a cookie or get any headers from asp.net web api to client with CORS?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, cookies, cross-domain

I can't save a cookie or get any headers from asp.net web api using CORS. But in postman I can see every header or cookie set in response.

My frontend request:

```js
var response = await fetch("https://localhost:7072/api/Auth/Register", {
            method: "post",
            mode: "cors",
            credentials: "same-origin",
            headers: {
                "Origin": "https://localhost:3000"
            },
            body: new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"))
        });
        response.headers.forEach((val, key) => console.log(key + ": " + val));
```

I also tried `credentials: include` but I cant get the headers anyway

But in response headers I get only `content-length: 0` and no cookie set.

My backend policy is:

```cs
builder.Services.AddCors(options => 
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:3000")
        .AllowAnyHeader().
        AllowCredentials().
        AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});
```

Build:

```cs
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

app.Run();
```

And `Auth/Register` looks like:

```cs
var token = GenerateToken(user);
Response.Cookies.Append("LOGIN_INFO", token, new CookieOptions
{
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3),
    HttpOnly = true,
    Secure = true
});
return Ok();
```

I tried using SameSite.None, Lax etc.

Comment: Why do you set the "Origin" header in your request?